# Comparison Between affordable Image Editor (Photoshop) / Creator VS. Free Image Software

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector, gimp, software-recommendation

Lately I would like to get involved / to learn in graphics design.

Since holidays are in full swing, I thought I would use this time.

I have used GIMP before, although very minimal and Blender. Both of which seem a bit complicated to me in terms of usage (perhaps this was due to the fact that I didn't really have the interest for this).

But now I do and I would not mind investing money in getting one.

My question here is:

1.)

How do the aforementioned compared to Photoshop?

There are so many different kinds of Photoshop and so:

2.)

Could you please cite the difference between them (i.e. Illustrator? CS6? Photoshop?)

I hope some of you experts can enlighten me on this based upon your personal experience, as I am trying to get my feet wet here.

*My primary use with it* would be in conjunction with **iOS** and **Android** Development.

Happy Holidays.

Comment: This question is a bit broad. You could simply compare the feature lists at the manufacturer's web sites.

Comment: These types of questions aren't a good fit for the Stack Exchange network. For more information, see this blog post: [**Gorilla vs. Shark**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/)

Comment: I think the asker will have little use for a comparison list of products. S/he seems to not know very much about where to start, and those lists will probably be largely meaningless. Not being familiar of the terminology it would be gobbledegook. By far the most important thing in this Q, I think, is that the asker seems not to know the difference between vector and bitmap. And, a question like this would be a good opportunity to suggest pen an paper, instead of going directly to sw. A million-dollar guitar does not make you into a Clapton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could you please cite the difference between them (i.e. Illustrator?
>   CS6? Photoshop?)

With this, it seems you are not familiar with the difference between Photoshop and Illustrator. The difference is enormous, as they are respectively bitmap and vector programmes (I know there are a Q here on GD somewhere that explains it well, I just cannot find it). So please research this, it is extremely important to what sort of design you hope to do.

[Here is an explanation.](http://vector-conversions.com/vectorizing/raster_vs_vector.html)

Myself, I am a stauch fan of vector graphics and use only bitmap (photoshop) when absolutely necessary. I am also a great fan of pen and paper...

Gimp is the open-source *bitmap* programme (photoshop), Inkscape is the open-source *vector* programme (Illustrator).

Play with these first, I think is wise; and then at a later stage you can consider buying one or both.

Blender is primarily 3D, and yes, it can be daunting if you are not familiar with the terms. Getting into graphic design, I would say you could hold out on Blender for a good while.

Comment: Can you tell me a bit more the reason why you personally prefer vector graphics over bitmap? And as far as pen and paper goes, I like drawing with pencil as well, but how would you at a later stage transform your pen-and-paper artwork into a digital product, which nowadays is almost always a requirement?

Comment: By the way, I am just looking for advise and suggestions from more experienced users. I would not get a Les Paul and call myself Clapton, let alone the fact that I have limited budget investing in a graphics design software.

Comment: Part 1: Certainly; but some of these answers might require a new question for practical reasons. I am a vector fan for the reason of scalability it can be scaled infinitely. Bitmaps does not scale well, as seen is the link in my answer. BUT: vector vs bitmap is a bit like comparing apples and tomatoes. Both are fruits, not both works well in a green salad. I scribble sketches on pieces of paper, post-its, napkins: whatever is at hand. I mainly do web design and some print design, so I work on paper and then recreate in code. >

Comment: Part 2: 1. re-create the rough sketches digitally (either in Illustrator, or more often in my case, directly in HTML and CSS for web design). or 2., in the case of _drawings_ I scan and manipulate. See this post for description of the latter: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25374/what-are-some-techniques-to-drawing-abstract-art/25376#25376

Comment: (yes, I got that you were just after some advice, I did not indicate that you pretended to be a Clapton. Just that software is not always the most important part. No offence intended)

Comment: Will definitely read everything you have provided here thoroughly and compose more questions if needed. No offense taken. Happy Holidays.

Comment: No problem; these relatively short comment fields can sometimes result in answers that might seem a little terse. Not intended.

Answer (score 1):

As far as Gimp goes, my web development company has used it for 10 years without issue, and it can handle Photoshop files just fine. So start with that to make sure you'll be continuing with it and, later, you can decide if you really need the additional features of Photoshop.

While many will now espouse the virtues of PS over Gimp, the reality is, you will never use those features for what you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks, Rob. Upvoted but boblet's answer gave me more texture on the subject. Happy holidays.